テキストファイルから「ANコード」を探す
「ANコード」を拾おうとすると「J」がついた「JANコード」が全て選ばれてしまいます。
どうしたらよいですか？
「J」の抜けを拾い、input.txtの何行目が抜けているか探したいのですが。
ソースコードは以下です。
class MainWindow(CTk):
    # ... existing code ...

    def check_input_file(self):
        try:
            with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()

            numeric_lines = []
            an_code_lines = []

            for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
                # 13桁の数値のみの行をチェック
                if re.match(r'^\d{13}$', line.strip()):
                    numeric_lines.append(i)

                # 「JANコード」が「ANコード」になっている箇所をチェック
                if 'ANコード' in line:
                    an_code_lines.append(i)

            message = ""
            if numeric_lines:
                message += f"13桁の数値のみの行: {', '.join(map(str, numeric_lines))}\n"
            if an_code_lines:
                message += f"「ANコード」が見つかった行: {', '.join(map(str, an_code_lines))}\n"

            if message:
                messagebox.showinfo("チェック結果", message)
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("チェック結果", "問題は見つかりませんでした。")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            messagebox.showerror("エラー", "input.txtファイルが見つかりません。")
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("エラー", f"ファイルのチェック中にエラーが発生しました： {str(e)}")

    # ... existing code ...


"JANコード"という文字列に"ANコード"が含まれている以上、仕方ないと思います。
文字列内にどのように"ANコード"が含まれているかにもよりますが、正規表現で /[^J]?ANコード/ のようにJが含まれないANコードにマッチさせれば良いのでは?

スマートではないかもしれませんが「「JANコード」が全て選ばれてしまいます。」であれば後処理で除外すれば良いのではないでしょうか？

特に補完や推測を必要としない、そのまま動かして試せる完結したソースコードとサンプルデータを用意して、望ましい結果と現状の出力がどのようなものかを実例で示すと具体的な助言・回答が出やすいと思われます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容をブラッシュアップしてみてください。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方

reパッケージで数字だけの行を判別できてるので, 同じように r'\WANコード'などと指定すればよいのでは？(re.searchで) ... \WANでは英数字が直前に付かないことを意味するけど, 直前の英字を除外(数字は許可)するなら [^A-Z]AN

正規表現r'[^J]?ANコード'で検索しても、'JANコード'内の'ANコード'が検索されてしまうのは変わりません。また、r'\WANコード'だと文字列先頭の'ANコード'が検索できません。やるならr'(?<!J)ANコード'やr'\bANコード'あたりではないでしょうか。

条件に「'JANコード' を含まない」を追加しました。
（追記）
ただし，'ANコード' と 'JANコード' を両方含んでいる行があると誤判定します。
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line, end='')
# 001,JANコード
# 002,ANコード
# 003,JANコード
# 004,JANコード
# 005,ANコード
# 006,JANコード
# 007,JANコード
# 008,JANコード
# 009,ANコード
# 010,JANコード

an_code_lines = []
for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    if ('ANコード' in line) and ('JANコード' not in line):
        an_code_lines.append(i)

for i in an_code_lines:
    print(lines[i - 1], end='')
# 002,ANコード
# 005,ANコード
# 009,ANコード


もし仮に"# ANコード1,JANコード2"のように"ANコード"と"JANコード"を両方含んでいる行があると、誤判定してしまうのでは？　そういった混在行が一切ない、あるいは混在行は無視しても問題ないという前提であれば、andとnotを使ったアドホックな判定でもよいと思いますが、現状の質問文にはそういった前提仕様は書かれておらず、具体的にどのようなテキストファイルを想定しているのかが質問文だけでは分からないので、仮定に基づくような万全ではないアドホックな方法では、一般的な回答としては不十分だと思います。まずは仕様を明確にするために質問者にヒアリングするべきかと。

指摘ありがとうございます。回答に追記しました。
